# how can I show a value under the days of a calander when a user clicks on any day

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to show a value to user under the days of a calander(for example price of that day) when he clicks on a day in flutter's default calander. how can I do that. I want it to be displayed in the place of the picture below:

[image]

***Update***
here is what I have tried now, just a date and time picker that I show to user after clicking a button:

```
Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });

    }
    final TimeOfDay timePicked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: selectedTime,
      );
      if (picked != null && timePicked != selectedTime) {
        setState(() {
          selectedTime = timePicked;

        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: @geekymano provide some code. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file which draws the dayPicker widget. it located here:

> {flutter_dir}/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart

You can edit the file (which I don't recommend) or fork the package and change it (or any other way that you prefer).

Use below dayWidget instead of the original one:

```
Widget dayWidget = Container(
      decoration: decoration,
      child: Center(
        child: Semantics(
          label: '${localizations.formatDecimal(day)}, ${localizations.formatFullDate(dayToBuild)}',
          selected: isSelectedDay,
          child: ExcludeSemantics(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(localizations.formatDecimal(day), style: itemStyle)
              ] + (isSelectedDay ? <Widget>[Text('Custome text')] : <Widget>[])),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

You need to pass the variable to the widget as well.

Update: to pass a parameter use below code:

```
DayPicker({
    Key key,
    @required this.selectedDate,
    @required this.currentDate,
    @required this.onChanged,
    @required this.firstDate,
    @required this.lastDate,
    @required this.displayedMonth,
    this.selectableDayPredicate,
    this.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.down,
    this.optionalText //Added
  }) : assert(selectedDate != null),
       assert(currentDate != null),
       assert(onChanged != null),
       assert(displayedMonth != null),
       assert(dragStartBehavior != null),
       assert(!firstDate.isAfter(lastDate)),
       assert(selectedDate.isAfter(firstDate) || selectedDate.isAtSameMomentAs(firstDate)),
       super(key: key);

  /// The currently selected date.
  ///
  /// This date is highlighted in the picker.
  final DateTime selectedDate;

  final String optionalText; // Added
```

Comment: it is a bit confusing for me inside the dayPicker and the IDE does not work there. how should I add an optional variable named customText there to show inside the Text widget that you have added?

Comment: Use vscode. it allows you to change the file. (Although I believe other IDEs let you edit with some warnings). for the other part, check the answer. I've updated it